# exit().remove() is not removing the first bar

Tags: d3.js

Whenever the slider is dragged and a new date is selected it does not redraw the first bar, it redraws all the other bars. For example, try date 09/06 and then 09/17. The first bar for id 54042 will not redraw. This is the link to my bl.ocks http://blockbuilder.org/fall16mis/87a39bc00b1b356f78dfd0954f345444

This is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    .tooltip {
              opacity: 0;
              background-color: #ffe047;
        position: absolute;
        }

    .grid line {
      stroke: lightgrey;
      shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }

    .ticks {
      font-size: 11px;
    }

    .track,
    .track-inset,
    .track-overlay {
      stroke-linecap: round;
    }

    .track {
      stroke: #000;
      stroke-opacity: 0.3;
      stroke-width: 10px;
    }

    .track-inset {
      stroke: #ddd;
      stroke-width: 8px;
    }

    .track-overlay {
      pointer-events: stroke;
      stroke-width: 50px;
      stroke: transparent;
      cursor: crosshair;
    }

    .handle {
      fill: #fff;
      stroke: #000;
      stroke-opacity: 0.5;
      stroke-width: 1.25px;
    }

    .bar:hover{
      fill:#0f9fff;
    }

    .legend{
        color:#005ebc;
      z-index:0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="slider"></div>
  <script>
    var json_data = "id,date,start_time,end_time\n\
54042,2017/09/06,5.50,5.53\n\
54042,2017/09/06,7.55,9.19\n\
54042,2017/09/16,11.12,12.28\n\
54042,2017/09/23,13.56,15.03\n\
54042,2017/09/07,16.29,17.33\n\
54042,2017/09/06,19.56,20.53\n\
54042,2017/09/20,21.3,22.14\n\
98765,2017/09/06,5.1,6.51\n\
98765,2017/09/06,11.4,11.53\n\
98765,2017/09/06,12.2,12.42\n\
98765,2017/09/06,12.55,14.2\n\
98765,2017/09/16,21.42,21.59\n\
98765,2017/09/16,22.01,23.13\n\
98765,2017/09/16,23.16,23.51\n\
98765,2017/09/23,13.41,14.03\n\
65299,2017/09/06,7.23,8.21\n\
65299,2017/09/06,9.37,10.23\n\
65299,2017/09/06,11.46,13.29\n\
65299,2017/09/06,18.07,19.57\n\
65299,2017/09/17,14.41,16.22\n\
65299,2017/09/17,21.39,23.39\n\
79408,2017/09/06,9.37,10.17\n\
79408,2017/09/06,11.03,12.08\n\
79408,2017/09/06,13.14,15.53\n\
79408,2017/09/06,16.05,17.48\n\
79408,2017/09/06,19.47,20.23\n\
38338,2017/09/06,8.22,9.28\n\
38338,2017/09/06,11.34,12.17\n\
38338,2017/09/07,12.43,13.35\n\
38338,2017/09/07,14.12,15.48\n\
38338,2017/09/07,16.09,17.23\n\
38338,2017/09/07,18.31,19.19\n\
38338,2017/09/07,21.49,23.26\n\
81757,2017/09/06,6.31,7.41\n\
81757,2017/09/06,8.18,9.39\n\
81757,2017/09/06,10.18,11.23\n\
81757,2017/09/06,13.02,14.04\n\
81757,2017/09/07,15.22,17.23\n\
81757,2017/09/07,20.32,22.01\n\
68077,2017/09/06,11.1,12.45\n\
68077,2017/09/06,15.23,16.54\n\
68077,2017/09/06,17.31,19.05\n\
68077,2017/09/06,20.39,21.3\n\
68077,2017/09/06,21.41,22.37\n\
58381,2017/09/06,16.51,17.55\n\
58381,2017/09/06,19.34,20.55\n\
58381,2017/09/06,21.33,22.51\n\
58381,2017/09/07,14.46,16.15\n\
37500,2017/09/06,8.2,10.18\n\
37500,2017/09/06,11.37,13.34\n\
37500,2017/09/06,19.22,20.16\n\
37500,2017/09/06,21.55,22.09\n\
37500,2017/09/16,14.16,16.26\n\
37500,2017/09/16,16.58,17.48\n\
39146,2017/09/06,19.47,20.21\n\
39146,2017/09/06,20.35,21.29\n\
39146,2017/09/06,22.01,23.25\n\
39146,2017/09/16,8.03,9.56\n\
39146,2017/09/16,10.23,12.52\n\
39146,2017/09/16,13.25,14.28";

    window.data = d3.csvParse(json_data, function(d){ return {
      id:d.id, 
      date:d.date, 
      start_time:+d.start_time,
        end_time:+d.end_time}; });

    window.minDate = d3.min(window.data,function(d){ return d.date; });

    window.maxDate = d3.max(window.data,function(d){ return d.date; });

    window.names = window.data.map(function(d){
      return d.id; });

    var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%Y/%m/%d");
    var displayDate = d3.timeFormat("%m/%d");
    var forChartDate = d3.timeFormat("%Y/%m/%d");

    var height = 500;
    var width = 800;
    var margin = {left: 50, right: 20, bottom: 0, top: 70};

    var tooltip = d3.select("body").append("div").attr("class", "tooltip")

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("height","1000px").attr("width","100%");

    var chartGroup = svg.append("g").attr("transform","translate("+margin.left+","+(margin.top+10)+")");

    var legend = svg.append("g").attr("transform","translate("+margin.left+","+(margin.top+10)+")");

    var chartDate = window.minDate;

    var displaySlider = function(data){

        window.x = d3.scaleLinear()
                   .domain([0, 24])
                   .range([0, width]);

        window.y = d3.scaleBand()
                   .domain(window.names)
                   .rangeRound([height, 0])
                   .paddingInner(0.3);

      function make_y_gridlines() {
        return d3.axisLeft(y)
        };

      function make_x_gridlines() {
        return d3.axisBottom(x)
        };

        chartGroup.append("g")
                .attr("class","axis y")
                .call(d3.axisLeft(y))

        chartGroup.append("g")
                .attr("class","axis x")
                        .call(d3.axisBottom(x))
               .attr("transform","translate(0,"+height+")")
                .call(d3.axisBottom(x)
                            .ticks(24));

      chartGroup.append("g")
              .attr("class", "grid")
              .call(make_y_gridlines()
                .tickSize(-width)
                .tickFormat("")
              );

      chartGroup.append("g")
              .attr("class", "grid")
              .call(make_x_gridlines()
                .tickSize(height)
                .tickFormat("")
              )

        var newData = data.filter(function(d){
          return d.date==chartDate;
        })

      displayBar(newData);

      var x1 = d3.scaleTime()
                 .range([0, width])
                 .domain([parseDate(minDate), parseDate(maxDate)])
                 .clamp(true);

      var slider = svg.append("g")
                      .attr("class", "slider")
                      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + ",30)");

      slider.append("line")
            .attr("class", "track")
            .attr("x1", x1.range()[0])
            .attr("x2", x1.range()[1])
            .select(function() { return this.parentNode.appendChild(this.cloneNode(true)); })
            .attr("class", "track-inset")
            .select(function() { return this.parentNode.appendChild(this.cloneNode(true)); })
            .attr("class", "track-overlay")
            .call(d3.drag()
                  .on("start.interrupt", function() { slider.interrupt(); })
                  .on("drag end", function() { sliderFunc(x1.invert(d3.event.x)); }));

          slider.insert("g", ".track-overlay")
            .attr("class", "ticks")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + 10 + ")")
            .selectAll("text")
            .data(x1.ticks(15))
            .enter()
            .append("text")
            .attr("x", x1)
            .attr("y", 10)
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .text(function(d) { return displayDate(d); });

      var label = slider.append("text")  
                        .attr("class", "label")
                        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                        .text(minDate)
                        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (-10) + ")");

      var handle = slider.insert("circle", ".track-overlay")
                          .attr("class", "handle")
                          .attr("r", 7);

      function sliderFunc(h) {
        handle.attr("cx", x1(h));
        label.attr("x", x1(h))
             .text(displayDate(h));
        chartDate = forChartDate(h);
        console.log(chartDate);
        newData = data.filter(function(d){
          return d.date==chartDate;
        })
        //displayText(newData);
        displayBar(newData);
      }
    };

    var displayBar = function(data){

      var bars = chartGroup.selectAll(".bar")
                                             .data(data, function(d){
                                            console.log(d);
                                                                return d;
                                                });

      bars.exit().remove();

      bar_enter = bars.enter().append("rect")

      bar_enter.attr("class", "bar")
               .attr("x", function(d) { 
        console.log(d.start_time);
        return window.x(d.start_time); })
               .attr("y", function(d) { return window.y(d.id); })
               .attr("height", window.y.bandwidth())
               .attr("fill", "green")
               .transition()
                .duration(600)
                        .attr("width", function(d) { return     window.x(d.end_time-d.start_time); });

      bar_enter.on('mousemove', function(d,i){
        tooltip.style("opacity","1")
               .style("left",(d3.event.pageX+10)+"px")
               .style("top",d3.event.pageY+"px");
        tooltip.html(" Start Time:"+d.start_time+" End Time:"+d.end_time);
      })

      bar_enter.on('mouseout', function(){
        tooltip.style("opacity","0")
      });
    };

     displaySlider(window.data);
  </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use the whole object in the key function:

```
var bars = chartGroup.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(data, function(d){
        return d;
    });
```

The [API](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selection_data) explains it:

> key function may be specified to control which datum is assigned to which element, replacing the default join-by-index, by computing **a string identifier** for each datum and element. (emphasis mine)

Therefore, instead of using the whole object, use a property (like the id):

```
var bars = chartGroup.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(data, function(d){
        return d.id;
    });
```

Here is the updated bl.ocks: https://bl.ocks.org/GerardoFurtado/57d014aa5124bdbe5774e1457816ff43/07a233d46aa3ae91bcffb8682de9ed8376c99b9a

Comment: Thank for the reply. Now, the bar is not on the wrong id but it still does not redraw the first bar at the correct time. For example, when we select 09/17 after 09/06 the first bar for id 65299 should start at 14.41 but it does not. It will be great if you could help me with this.

Comment: @fall16mis I'm not following, it is starting at 14.41 to me. Please chek it again.

Comment: It is working fine after I returned d.start_time as well. Thanks! `code` var bars = chartGroup.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(data, function(d){
        return d.id, d.start_time;
    });

Comment: @fall16mis yes, you can combine any properties you want to get a **unique** string.... as long as you have a **string**.